# binding reference of type 'type' to value of type 'const type' drops 'const' qualifier

Tags: c++, constants, pass-by-reference, function-call

This issue looks like known one. but i have no any const in types.
What I am missing?
I have the following code:

```
class PlanForBlock 
{
public:
void registerExtraIterator(DummyLoadIterator *ExtraIterator, const SIImpl *SInfo, Iterator2AGUAssignmentAnalisisVMP7& Iterator2AGUAnalisis) {
    assert(ExtraIterator && "Not an EyeQVMPDummyLoadIterator!");
    ExtraIterators.push_back(ExtraIterator);
    if (SInfo->hasEyeQVMP7()) {
      bool IsGenXYIt = ExtraIterator->containsDummyIterKind(GenXY);
      Iterator2AGUAnalisisVMP7.addIterator(ExtraIterator, SBNonMasked,
                                                 IsGenXYIt);
    }
  }
};

class OtherClass
{
private:
Iterator2AGUAssignmentAnalisis Iterator2AGUAssignAnalisis;
public:
DummyLoadIterator *
  generateAndRegisterDummyLoad(AGUPlanForBlock &PlanForBlock,
                               DummyLoadIteratorKind Kind) const;

}
DummyLoadIterator *OtherClass::generateAndRegisterDummyLoad(
    PlanForBlock &PForBlock, DummyLoadIteratorKind Kind) const {
  auto *Iter = initDummyLoad(PlanForBlock.getBlock(), {}, Kind);
  PBlock.registerExtraIterator(Iter, SInfo, Iterator2AGUAssignAnalisisVMP7);
  return Iter;
}
```

The error

```
error: binding reference of type 'Iterator2AGUAssignmentAnalisis' to value of type 'const Iterator2AGUAssignmentAnalisisVMP7' drops 'const' qualifier
  PForBlock.registerExtraIterator(Iter, SInfo, Iterator2AGUAssignAnalisis);
                                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
File.h:498:135: note: passing argument to parameter 'Iterator2AGUAnalisisVMP7' here
  void registerExtraIterator(DummyLoadIterator *ExtraIterator, const SIImpl *SInfo, Iterator2AGUAssignmentAnalisis& Iterator2AGUAnalisis)
```

Comment: *but i have no any const in types* - I see very clear `const` qualifier on `generateAndRegisterDummyLoad` method. That means all of the members within this method are implicitly `const`.

Comment: Yksisarvinen's probably right, but I'm unable to reproduce the problem with the provided code: https://godbolt.org/z/5en74Yhx4 .

Comment: `PascalCase` for everything and long names with no indication or special naming for member variables makes this very hard for me to read.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear where the variable `Iterator2AGUAssignAnalisisVMP7` is declared. I suspect that it is the data member `Iterator2AGUAssignAnalisis`.

```
class OtherClass
{
private:
Iterator2AGUAssignmentAnalisis Iterator2AGUAssignAnalisis;
//...
```

But in any case the function `generateAndRegisterDummyLoad`

```
DummyLoadIterator *
  generateAndRegisterDummyLoad(AGUPlanForBlock &PlanForBlock,
                               DummyLoadIteratorKind Kind) const;
```

is a constant member function. So the argumment  `Iterator2AGUAssignAnalisisVMP7`  is a constant. So a constant variable may not be bound with a non-constant reference in this call

```
PBlock.registerExtraIterator(Iter, SInfo, Iterator2AGUAssignAnalisisVMP7);
```